# Android Studio 3.0 - How to make a toggleimage that fit

Tags: java, android, imageview, android-studio-3.0, togglebutton

I may be asking a basic question, but to be honest, I have no real developement or code knowledge. I've been requested to make a prototybe of some basic app, that is supposed mainly to be buttons on screens, activable or disactivable.

I've been coding this on Android Studio 3.0, I (hardly) managed to place PNGs files on the screen, making it looking like a button. When I was pressing it, nothing happened of course, so I searched there and there how to make it change when pressed This worked

```
        casedanger1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch(event.getAction())
            {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN :
                    casedanger1.setImageResource(R.drawable.casedanger1slct);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP :
                    casedanger1.setImageResource(R.drawable.casedanger1);
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

But when I try to disable again the button, it doesn't revert to the standard image (casedanger1)

How should I proceed ? I've been searching for days without a real solution. I have tried to make it a toggle button, which works, but makes the image bigger, and thus cropped.

Any hints that could help ? I'm really desperated, this is not something I'm familiar with.

Thank you
-Pliskin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you were close.  Try this

```
    casedanger1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
    // track if the image is selected or not
    boolean isSelected = false;

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(isSelected) {
                casedanger1.setImageResource(R.drawable.casedanger1slct);
        } else {
                casedanger1.setImageResource(R.drawable.casedanger1);
        }
        // toggle the boolean
        isSelected = !isSelected;
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes ! It's totally working, and it gives me exactly what I need! One question, one answer, one solution. This is perfect !
Thank you ! I can now progress again on the project ! :D
Have a good day sir !